# Why didn't my self-answer get Snaphat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I have answered my [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397171/how-to-run-mojolicious-appication-under-api-path-how-to-ignore-some-prefix-i/41397179#41397179) within 30 minutes, got +5 and the answer was accepted.

But [Snaphat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/snaphat) is not awarded

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 7):

Snaphat is only awarded for answering *someone else's question*, not your own question. Answering within 30 minutes and marking it as accepted is much easier when it is your own question..

There is a separate hat for answering your own question, [Egoist](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/egoist), which requires that both your question and your answer reach a score of 3.